Firebase storage automatically deleting apk file after upload
When I upload an image in firebase storage it keeps the image but when I upload an apk file its automatically disappears. What is the problem
I want to upload an apk file in firebase storage for my project.
I tried many times, but not Working.

Firebase Storage (on the free plan) no longer allows hosting of certain types of executables, as they are often used in abuse scenarios.
From the documentation on uploading files:

For Spark plan projects, Firebase blocks upload and hosting of certain executable file types for Windows (files with .exe, .dll and .bat extensions), Android (.apk extension) and Apple (.ipa extension) by Cloud Storage for Firebase and Firebase Hosting. This policy exists to prevent abuse on our platform. Projects on the Blaze plan are not affected. For more information, see this FAQ.

You'll either have to upgrade to the paid plan, or find a different platform to host them.
